# Manually create/use a DI container in PHP?

Tags: php, dependency-injection

I'm trying to understand how to use a DI Container.

Let's say I have three classes : A, B, and C defined like so :

```
class A {}

class B
{
    private $a;

    public function set_a(A $a)
    {
        $this->a = $a;
    }
}

class C
{
    private $b;

    public function set_b(B $b)
    {
        $this->b = $b;
    }
}
```

Now what I don't really get, is what I am supposed to write in index.php. I've read it's not a good thing to instantiate a Container and then pass it to my objects so that they can use it because it makes my objects dependent on the container. But does it mean, then, that I must write something like this in index.php :

```
$container = new Container();
$container->a = function($ctnr) {
    return new A();
}
$container->b = function($ctnr) {
    $b = new B();
    $b->set_a($ctnr->a);
    return $b;
}
$container->b = function($ctnr) {
    $c = new C();
    $c->set_b($ctnr->b);
    return $c;
}

$c = $container->c;
```

Is this the way to go ?

Answer (score 0):

The whole idea about the container is to resolve dependencies and perform initialization of objects.

I would do:
Choose your container. I wrote one, for fun, that is being used in several applications. (https://github.com/niclaslindberg/webx-ioc/).
Design your dependencies with interfaces. (Only allow classes to depend on other interfaces). Register your classes/instances and let the container do all the dirty work.

Answer (score -1):

I think you understood the concept.

The basic idea of dependency injection is that you delegate the instantiation of an object to a framework.

You can write your own container but I recommend that you use a framework.

Most frameworks allow you to decide what types and where they should be injected.

[Symfony](https://github.com/symfony/DependencyInjection) is a pretty good container.